# xlrd & openpyxl fetch wrong cell values (Excel)

Tags: python, excel, cell

Need help, please! Seems like a simple task – I need to fetch values from certain spreadsheet cells and sum them up. But I failed even at the first step - fetching them. At first, I thought smth wrong was with the module (openpyxl is being regularly upgraded and I missed something), but the xlrd module produced the same wrong results! Here's the code:

```
import xlrd, xlwt
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"E:\Projects_working (11).xlsx")
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Language Process')
for i in range(1, 100):
    cellVal = sheet.cell(i, 14).value   #need to find "5" in column 14
       if type(cellVal) == float and cellVal == 5.0: #need to read corresp.
           print(sheet.cell(i, 11).value)            #values в column 11
```

As a result, instead of an integer (say, 22), the code ends up with a float 42782.61458. (The other values are similar and wrong: 42782.66146, 42781.38542, 42781.42708, etc.)

Orignially I used the openpyxl module and added the flag data_only=True to the loadede workbook: wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True). That code produces the same results. Without this flag, all get is strange formulas: =B32+((M32-B32)/2), =B41+((M41-B41)/2) etc. Here's the code for these formulas (with no flag):

```
import openpyxl
wb =  openpyxl.load_workbook(r"E:\Projects_working (11).xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Language Process')
for i in range(1, 100):
    cellVal = sheet.cell(row=i, column=14).value
        if type(cellVal) == float and cellVal == 5.0:
            print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value)
```

And here's a link to the file, just in case: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bFhkEs8JTVWCgZoW5_9lQ1q_T0gtijBhuywr6OVpfGc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The data you are reading look like Excel's version of raw datetime values. You probably have miscounted the columns (that is, given the wrong column index).

Comment: John, you're awesome! Thanx so much, man! (Good Gosh! I was looking for some tricky reasons, whereas the mistake was plain to see!)